# Sharing local *.nmf's that are stored on separate drive for ArcGIS Explorer Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-explorer

I am trying to use ArcGIS Explorer to give administrators basic access to maps that are stored in a drive that is specifically for GIS use. We don't want the data stored on the drive that they use because of the possibility of them accidentally altering the maps. We have no server access and cloud services are out because of sensitive data.

I have application configurations set up and linked to the map on my network drive and set the ArcExplorer map to store relative paths.

The problem is that when the map is opened through Explorer, it always opens as "default map" and all the layer file links are broken. I have tried changing the order in which I set it all up but so far, the results remain the same.

Comment: Relative paths are likely your issue. Try setting to UNC and seeing what happens  http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisexplorer/900/en/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried setting to UNC and it did not work but there was a reason for it. Taking a closer look, I found that the broken paths were linking to a location that I was not using. They were looking at a hidden folder in my user file that was associated with ArcGIS Explorer. Once I deleted those files it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a closer look at my broken paths, I found that they were they were leading to a hidden folder in my user file that was associated with ArcGIS Explorer. Once I deleted those files the map started working again with no broken paths.